# Create a stored procedure in PostgreSQL that is never rolled back?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions, rollback

From the [PostgreSQL 9.0 manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-sequence.html):

> Important: To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain
>   numbers from the same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled
>   back; that is, once a value has been fetched it is considered used,
>   even if the transaction that did the nextval later aborts. This means
>   that aborted transactions might leave unused "holes" in the sequence
>   of assigned values. setval operations are never rolled back, either.

So, how can I create a PL\PgSQL function with the same behaviour: "operation is never rolled back"?
In a call like this, whatever the function changes will NOT be rolled back:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT composite_nextval(...);
ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **savepoint** after selecting `composite_nextval`. Then, just rollback to that **savepoint** and commit the rest.

Something like this:

```
BEGIN;
    SELECT composite_nextval(...);
    SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
    INSERT INTO some_table(a) VALUES (2);
    ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
COMMIT;
```

This way, `select composite_nextval(...)` will be committed, but `insert into some_table` will not.

Comment: I believe the question was how to make a function whose side-effect persists _even if a rollback occurs_, but your answer, unless I misunderstand, translates to "just make sure not to rollback all the way".

Comment: yeah, these are referred to as autonomous transactions which pg doesn't directly support.  HOWEVER, you can use dblink to establish a new connection back to the db within a transaction and get the equivalent that way.

Comment: Like @ryanc comment I want "make sure not to rollback all the way" in the exactly 'nextval' behaviour. In fact I'd like to make a function to make the same thing the 'nextval' function but specifically for composite/multicolumn primary keys (PK). Eg if I have 2 fields in PK where one is a foreign key (FK) and another is a 'serial' like field, but this serial will use the DEFAULT composite_nextval( ... ) instead nextval the PK's will be (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), ... instead (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,6).